# Error in plugin I am using for poll in website

Tags: php, file, permission-denied

I am getting some errors.

1.file_put_contents(C:\Inetpub\vhosts\mystateinfo.com\httpdocs\AP201-205\AP201-205\web/app.data/demo-your-first-poll.def/ip-block.txt) [function.file-put-contents]: failed

2.to open stream: Permission denied in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\mystateinfo.com\httpdocs\AP201-205\AP201-205\web\app.ajax-

the above permission error is in following code

```
    {
        file_put_contents( $this->path_data, "={$this->ipaddr}\r\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX );
        return true;
    }
```

3.Can not write [app.data] (C:\Inetpub\vhosts\mystateinfo.com\httpdocs\AP201-205\AP201-205\web/app.data/demo-your-first-poll.def/votes.txt) (Could not get the lock!)

You can check this error on poll used in URL www.mystateinfo.com  at the bottom right side

Comment: You will have to set the correct access permissions for the directory that the script wants to write to on your server.

Comment: @CBroe I dont have much experience in php

Comment: how to do that?@CBroe

Comment: Then go ask your server admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with access permission on folder in which I was doing upload. You will have to provide the writing permission on that folder.Find permission settings at location of folder and Change access permissions accordingly in your server.